# Storybook test-runner seems to be failing on plain HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I am trying to run the test-runner from storybook, but I seems to get various errors based on that SB cant read plain HTML? Not sure what is happening, my development and build enviroments are working as expected but the test-runner just says nope.

This is the story that is working both in dev and build

```
export default {
  component: VCContent,
  title: 'Some title',
  decorators: [
    (Story) => {
      return <div className='some parent class'>{Story()}</div>;
    },
  ],
  args: {},
};

const Template = (args) => {
  return <div></div>;
};
```

These are the returned errors on the default test setup:

```
      x Expression expected
        ,-[/Users/Bram.Wesselink/repos/remark-components/web-components/velogica-configurator/vc-button/stories.jsx:17:1]
     17 | };
     18 | 
     19 | const Template = (args) => {
     20 |   return <div></div>;
        :          ^
     21 | };
     22 | 
     23 | export const Primary = Template.bind({});
        `----

      x Expression expected
        ,-[/Users/Bram.Wesselink/repos/remark-components/web-components/velogica-configurator/vc-button/stories.jsx:17:1]
     17 | };
     18 | 
     19 | const Template = (args) => {
     20 |   return <div></div>;
        :               ^
     21 | };
     22 | 
     23 | export const Primary = Template.bind({});
        `----

      x Unterminated regexp literal
        ,-[/Users/Bram.Wesselink/repos/remark-components/web-components/velogica-configurator/vc-button/stories.jsx:17:1]
     17 | };
     18 | 
     19 | const Template = (args) => {
     20 |   return <div></div>;
        :                ^^^^^^
     21 | };
     22 | 
     23 | export const Primary = Template.bind({});
        `----
```